# How to set a global variable in function

Tags: javascript

I read through similar topics, but couldn't find an answer.

Here is the code:

```
foo_arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
bar_arr = ["x", "y"]

test(bar_arr);
document.write(bar);

function test(arr_name) {
    bar = Math.random()*arr_name.length;

    if (bar < 1) {test(arr_name)}
}
```

As you can see I pass the array name to the function, but what if I need to pass a variable too? For instance

```
test(bar, bar_arr);

function test(var_name, arr_name) {
    var_name = Math.random()*arr_name.length;
```

It won't work. Why and how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass (references to) variables in JavaScript, only their values. Even with `bar_arr`, you are only passing the "value" of the array, which is an object -- you can modify the object's properties this way, but you can't change `bar_arr` itself.

To really "pass" a variable, take the above trick one step back and use the object which contains the variables as properties. In this case, that is the `window` object of which all global variables are a property:

```
function test(var_name) {
  window[var_name] = 'foo';
}

test('bar'); // note that the property name is a string, not a variable
alert(bar); // now the global 'bar' is set
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the value of only one global variable, you can return the wanted value from your fonction :

```
function test(arr_name) {
    return Math.random()*arr_name.length;
}

bar = test(bar_arr);
```

I'm really not sure that's what you want to do, but I'm glad if I was able to help.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about 'return', but can't figure out how to do the second part of the function: `if (bar < 1) {test(arr_name)}`

Answer (score 0):

If `var_name` is a global variable, you can still access it inside `function test`.
Example:

```
var_name; // global
function test(arr_name) {
    var_name = Math.random()*arr_name.length;  // still accessible here

    if (bar < 1) {test(arr_name)}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I need to run a function several times with different parameters and then to use these new variables in other functions.

Comment: Then, perhaps it would be better to follow @Krtek's cue and have the function return a value. You could push all the return values to a new array as you loop. I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried @casablanca's answer and it worked perfectly. The function is a bit longer then 2 lines and I can't figure out how to use a 'result' here since I still need these vars in this function.